# "How to update value of item initialized from getDerivedStateFromProps on some action"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have initialized some const, lets say `A`, using `getDerivedStateFromProps`. Now I want to update the value on some action using `setState` but it's not working.

```js
constructor(props) {

  super(props)
  this.state = {
   A: []
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
   const A = nextProps.A
   return {
    A
   }
  }

  handleDragStart(e,data) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('item', data)
  }

  handleDragOver(e) {

    e.preventDefault()
  }
  handleDrop(e, cat) {
    const id = e.dataTransfer.getData('item')

    const item = find(propEq('id', Number(id)), this.state.A)
    const data = {
     ...item.data,
     category: cat,
    }

    const val = {
     ...item,
     data
    }

    this.setState({
     A: item,
    })
  }

}
**Listing the items and Drag and Drop to Categorize**
{this.state.A.map((item, index) => (
                  <ListRow
                    key={`lm${index}`}
                    draggable
                    name={item.name ? item.name : ''}
                    description={item.data ? item.data.description : ''}
                    type={item.data ? item.data.target_types : ''}
                    source={item.data ? item.data.source : ''}
                    stars={item.data ? item.data.stars : []}
                    onDragStart={e => this.handleDragStart(e, item.id)}
                    onDragOver={e => this.handleDragOver(e)}
                    onDrop={e => this.handleDrop(e, 'process')}
                    onModal={() => this.handleToggleModal(item)}
                  />
                ))}
```

I expect the value of `A` to be an item from `HandleDrop` but it's returning the same value that is loaded from `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Comment: This approach is completly wrong. Why you are using `getDerivedStateFromProps` ? The purpos of `getDerivedStateFromProps` is either to update or not the state of the component which you already have done with `setState`. Also `nextProps` will contain A if you provide it as a prop from the parent Component.

Comment: I am using `getDerivedStateFromProps` to update the value of A  and it's provided as a prop from parent Component. Currently, there are two scenarios.           1.we need to add items from a form component (child of current )and on submitting we are loading the results as props from parent to current component. Once loaded . 2. We need to categorize this items and update the items. as `handleDrop()`

Comment: OK, but with these peace of code you've provided, no one can see the whole picture and what you're trying to achieve. It is not clear where and how you call `handleDrop`. Next in `handleDrop` you have variables like `val, data, id` you don't use, maybe they are not related to the issue you have, but again not clear.

Comment: @YordanNikolov I have updated the code block. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this problem.

> I used componentDidUpdate instead of getDerivedStatesFromProps.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
     if (!equals(this.props.A, prevPropsA)) {
      const A = this.props.A
      this.setState({
       A
      })
     }
    }
```

> And  the handleDrop function as

```
handleDrop(e, cat) {
            const id = e.dataTransfer.getData('item')
            const item = find(propEq('id', Number(id)), this.state.A)
            const data = {
             ....data,
             category: cat,
            }
            const val = {
             ...quota,
             data
            }

            let {A} = this.state

            const index = findIndex(propEq('id', Number(id)), A)
            if (!equals(index, -1)) {
             A = update(index, val, A)
            }
            this.setState({
             A
            })
           }
```

Thank you very much for all of your help. Any suggestions or feedback for optimizing this sol will be highly appreciated. Thanks